# Can a NSMutableArray contain nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning Objective-C and I have a question about NSArray. Can it contain nil? I read somewhere an NSArray cannot contain nil. Is this the same for NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither can contain nil. They'll raise an exception if you try to put it in. If you want to represent the idea of "nothing" in an array, set or dictionary, you can use NSNull.

Answer (score 5):

Since everybody seems so convinced that an `NSArray` cannot contain nil I want to add my two cents:

```
CFMutableArrayRef array = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 1, NULL);
CFArrayAppendValue(array, NULL);
NSLog(@"array: %@", array);
```

Remember that `CFMutableArrayRef` is toll-free bridged to its Cocoa counterpart `NSMutableArray`.

I admit that this is a constructed case and probably seldom in Cocoa.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put a `nil` inside an `NSMutableArray`. See ["NSMutableArray Class Doc"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDEFAA).